# For to multiply numbers

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

[image]

I want to create a code to multiply different values

The first operation will be 15 *4, then 19 *5

After 14 *4, then 17*5

```
Dim C as Range
Set C = Range("i9:i10")

For cell = 1 To C
   cell.Value = Cells(i, j) * Cells(i, j) 

'I thought about changing the identification of the cells to perform the calculations

Next
```

I would have another range for the second operation

Comment: Your loop is not correct. `For i = 1 to c` means `c` must be a number. Right now `c` is a range.

Comment: Why use VBA? Why not just use a formula in the cells?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have the products in the "X" and "Y" cells, I would not even use a VBA program for that, you might do this, using a formula. Imagine this is what your Excel sheet looks like:

```
      A    B    C    D    E    F
1 Layer   ys   yd    H    X    Y
2     I   15   14    4
3    II   19   17    5
```

In cell `E2`, you might put the formula:

```
=B2*$D2
```

The other cells, you get those by dragging and dropping the formula in the destination cells. What will happen?

As you drag to the right, the source column will change (from `B` column to `C`), you'll get `=C2*$D2`. `$D` will not change because of the dollar-sign (absolute referencing, this is called)
As you drag down, the source row will change (from `2` to `3`), you'll get `=B3*$D3` and `=C3*$D3`.

I imagine this is what you're looking for?